# AdMob is not showing ads after i submit my IOS application to appStore

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, admob

when I have programmed my IOS application on Xcode I use AdMob for the ads
and during the testing on the simulator
the AdMob test ads were showing correctly

BUT

after I submit my application to the app store and the application is published
when I download the application from the appStore there was no add
I am wondering if there is anything wrong with the code below

```
import GoogleMobileAds
var banner : GADBannerView! // Banner to the adds

   var interstitial: GADInterstitial!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()



    banner = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait)
    banner.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-8191182380005591/8534539***"
    banner.rootViewController = self
    let req : GADRequest = GADRequest()

    banner.load(req)
    banner.frame = CGRect(x:0 , y:  view.bounds.height - banner.frame.size.height , width : banner.frame.size.width ,  height: banner.frame.size.height )

    self.view.addSubview(banner)
    //show add
    self.interstitial =  createAndLoadInterstitial()



}
//CREAT ADD
func createAndLoadInterstitial() -> GADInterstitial {
    interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-8191182380005591/338872***")
 //   guard let interstitial = interstitial else {
    //    return nil
    //}

    let request = GADRequest()
   // request.testDevices =  [kGADSimulatorID]
    interstitial.delegate = self
    interstitial.load(GADRequest())
    return interstitial
}//FUNC



func interstitialDidReceiveAd(_ ad: GADInterstitial) {


    ad.present(fromRootViewController: self)
}
func interstitialDidFail(toPresentScreen ad: GADInterstitial) {

}
```

this is my code
Also, I link the application from AdMob to application on the appStore
are there anyone knew where is the problem with me
if it is not in the code where I should search

thanks

Comment: AdUnitIds are different. I think this could be the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after 3 week from publishing the app finally i can an ads

i think at the beginning there was no users using the app so this why there was no ads but after a while when the people start to download the app the ads show up